# Different order per locale for Structures

Tags: structure, ordering

I know this is a long shot, but is there a way to order a Structure differently per locale? As in the standard drag and drop ordering that comes with a structure but with the ordering saved for each locale.

I'm trying to avoid having to create a translatable entries field to achieve the same thing on an overview page, as that means whene

Comment: You can vote for it here: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/14846259-structure-order-dependant-on-locale